# Installing trac - "Trac requires Python 2.5 or later"

Tags: rhel, software-installation, python, trac

I am having a little trouble getting `trac 1.0` installed via `easy_install`:

```
[box]# easy_install Trac==1.0

Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/T/Trac/Trac-1.0.zip#md5=3dd2e883179879c8fa5b98c984f15058
Processing Trac-1.0.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-FOeJcG/Trac-1.0/setup.cfg
Running Trac-1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-FOeJcG/Trac-1.0/egg-dist-tmp-b2610A
Trac requires Python 2.5 or later
error: Setup script exited with 1
```

Python 2.6 is also installed on my system ( `/usr/bin/python26`, `/usr/include/python2.6/`, `/usr/lib/python2.6/`, `/usr/lib64/python2.6/`, ect ).

Could I pass one of these as a prefix for `easy_install`?  If so, which am I looking to include - the libs or the include path?

**EDIT**
Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8352224/721073) in SO, I tried making a symlink to python/python26.  Continue to get the same error as above.

Comment: If you have `python26` you probably need to install `setuptools26` which has a binary called `easy_install26` which specifically works with python 2.6.

Comment: I'll give that a try tomorrow.

Comment: Ok got it now.  I executed: `sh ./setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg` and now have a working `easy_install-2.6`.   Now to back up the sqlite database & see if I can get `Trac 1.0` installed.

Comment: Tried upgrading .12 to 1.0 per documentation.  Got no errors, looked fine, but after reloading httpd, I'm still seeing trac .12.

Comment: Blew out `Trac .12`, installed `Trac 1.0` with `easy_install-2.6` - it's up and running now.   If you'll put your comment as answer I'll be glad to give you some mojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue presented here is one which occurs when you use a distribution that has both Python2 and Python3 enabled in its repositories.  To resolve conflicts, the earlier versions have had their version numbers appended to the binary.

In the case with this question, a proper version of `setuptools` for Python v2.6 had to be installed to provide the `easy_install-2.6` binary.

Glad you got it solved!